# java: how to sign xml with x509 signature created from separate private key and public cert

Tags: java, xml, x509certificate

I need to sign an xml document.  I have a path to a private key and a path to a certificate.  Examples I see take these from a keystore but I don't want to put them into a keystore.

The call is made like this:

```
buildSignatureBlock(privateKeyPath,certificatePath);
```

My code is creating a signature block in the soap header that looks like this:

```
    <KeyInfo>
      <KeyValue>
        <RSAKeyValue>
          <Modulus>4om2CA8VG4...</Modulus>
          <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
        </RSAKeyValue>
      </KeyValue>
    </KeyInfo>
```

But I need it to look more like this:

```
            <KeyInfo>
                <X509Data>
                    <X509IssuerSerial>
                        <X509IssuerName>E=mari...</X509IssuerName>
                        <X509SerialNumber>00 eb 8e 89 7c .. .. .. ..</X509SerialNumber>
                    </X509IssuerSerial>
                    <X509Certificate>MIIC3jCCAke...</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
```

Here is the code that is producing it:

```
    private void buildSignatureBlock(String privateKeyPath, String publicKeyPath) {

    BufferedReader br;
    XMLSignature signature = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(privateKeyPath));
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        PEMParser pp = new PEMParser(br);
        PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair = (PEMKeyPair) pp.readObject();
        KeyPair kp = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getKeyPair(pemKeyPair);
        pp.close();

        DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(kp.getPrivate(), securityNode);

        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

        // Create a Reference to the enveloped document (in this case,
        // you are signing the whole document, so a URI of "" signifies
        // that, and also specify the SHA1 digest algorithm and
        // the ENVELOPED Transform.
        Reference ref = fac.newReference("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
                Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED,
                        (TransformParameterSpec) null)), null, null);

        //create the SignedInfo object, which is the object that is actually signed
        SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod
            (CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS,
            (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
            fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
            Collections.singletonList(ref));

        //create the optional KeyInfo object, which contains info that enables the recipient 
        //to find the key needed to validate the signature.
        KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();

        //use the KeyInfoFactory to create the KeyValue object and add it to a KeyInfo object
        KeyValue kv = kif.newKeyValue(kp.getPublic());
        KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(kv));

        //Finally, we create the XMLSignature object
        signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

        //generate the signature
        signature.sign(dsc);

        //The resulting document now contains a signature, 
        //which has been inserted as the last child element of the root element.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MarshalException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMLSignatureException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do I modify it to produce the correct signature block?

Comment: Key stores can be temporary and in memory. So ... why?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Try using `kif.newX509Data()` instead of `kif.newKeyValue()`. See Code  Sample 2 here https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/dig-signature-api.html . See also WSS4J. It may be helpful to build the SOAP header including signature

Comment: Thanks pedrofb.  I have changed my code per your example.  Now its creating an X509Data block but the details inside it are different from what I'm trying to get to.  I'm researching how to control what data/format is put into it.

Comment: @user3217883 Did you able to make it work?